# Let X be a random variable with $E(X^m) = (m+1)!2^m$,m = 1,2,3,..... Find the density of X.

Tags: probability-distributions

Let X be a random variable with $E(X^m) = (m+1)!2^m$,m = 1,2,3,..... Find the density of X.
I assumed it to be exponential and it turned out to be true. But i couldn't prove it.

Comment: To **prove** it, once you have made the correct conjecture, use the given information to compute the moment generating function of $X$, and compare with the known mgf of a suitable exponentially distributed random variable.

Comment: how to compute the the moment generating function of x?

Comment: The mgf is $\sum_0^\infty \frac{E(X^m)}{m!}t^m$, which is $\sum_0^\infty (m+1)2^m t^m$. This sum can be found by differentiating $\sum w^{m+1}$.

Answer (score 1):

We know that the moment-generating function of a random variable $X$ obeys the property $$M_X(t) = \operatorname{E}[e^{tX}] = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{\operatorname{E}[X^k]}{k!} t^k = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{M_X^{(k)}(0)}{k!} t^k,$$ so that $M_X^{(k)}(0) = \operatorname{E}[X^k]$.  Now if we substitute, we find $$M_X(t) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(k+1)!2^k}{k!} t^k = \sum_{k=0}^\infty (k+1) (2t)^k.$$  But observe that this is the formal derivative of the power series $$\frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=0}^\infty (2t)^{k+1} = \frac{1}{2} \frac{2t}{1-2t} = \frac{t}{1-2t},$$ so $$M_X(t) = \frac{d}{dt}\left[\frac{t}{1-2t}\right] = \frac{1}{(1-2t)^2}.$$ I leave the rest as a simple exercise.

Answer (score 0):

The MGF is
$$ E(\exp(sX)) = \sum_{m=0}^\infty E(X^m) \frac{s^m}{m!}$$

However, your formula does **not** match the MGF of an exponential distribution. What it does match is a Gamma distribution.